# MySQL Query for count of multiple values

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to retrieve the count of multiple values but can get only partial count.

My code

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, `dateadded` FROM s2 WHERE 'LEVEL` IN (1,2,3) and 
client = 'myuser' GROUP BY `LEVEL`,`dateadded` ORDER BY `dateadded` DESC 
LIMIT 1");
```

My table

```
client   dateadded     level
myuser   2019-01-21      3
myuser   2019-01-21      2
myuser   2019-01-21      5
myuser   2019-02-16      3
myuser   2019-02-16      2
myuser   2019-02-16      8
myuser   2019-02-16      2
```

My return value should be: 3  -> latest date (2019-02-19) and count of 1,2 and 3.

I want to count how many 1, 2 and 3 from the latest date only.

Thank you very much!!

Nathalie

Comment: Can you please show what your expected output should look like?

Comment: You can't get the "level" of one entry and also the count of each level in one SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your requirement is not clear, I assume you wanted the count of LEVEL, dateadded for the latest date alone.

This should help you:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, `dateadded` , `LEVEL` FROM s2 WHERE `LEVEL` IN 
(1,2,3) and 
client = 'myuser' GROUP BY `dateadded`,`LEVEL` ORDER BY `dateadded` DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

If you don't want to count by each level, then use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, `dateadded` FROM s2 WHERE `LEVEL` IN 
(1,2,3) and 
client = 'myuser' GROUP BY `dateadded` ORDER BY `dateadded` DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Last one was the key one! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, `dateadded` FROM s2 WHERE 'LEVEL' IN (1,2,3) and 
client = 'myuser' and `dateadded` IN (select max(dateadded) from s2) GROUP BY `LEVEL`,`dateadded` ORDER BY `dateadded` DESC 
LIMIT 1");
```